# Is there a comprehensive list of corpora of all the languages (maybe even dialects) of the world?

Tags: corpora

Is there a comprehensive list of corpora of all the languages of the world?

I've been searching on wikipedia eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_National_Corpus. If I scroll to the bottom, I do see a list of corpora. However, the list is heavily biased towards English corpora. Need something more representative of other languages, if possible.

I came across Sketch Engine. The scope's pretty good. Are there rival products or better products?

Answer (score 2):

The plain answer to this question is **no**.

A somewhat more lengthy answer is: There are some metadata harvesters around the world collecting data about corpora provided by repositories, one of the is the [CLARIN Virtual Language Observatory](https://vlo.clarin.eu) that provides a search over the complete corpus metadata and a facetted search for some specific metadata fields. Another one is the [OLAC Language Resource Catalog](http://search.language-archives.org/index.html). A third one is the [META-SHARE inventory](http://www.meta-share.org/). The content covered by those portals is overlapping, but also disjoint, and there are corpora out in the world that aren't findable by either of them.

Comment: great answer tq. however, any thoughts on software like Sketch Engine

Comment: The real problem with Sketch Engine is that it is a commercial enterprise making profit on the work of scientists and privatising it. In the journal market we see the dark side of this business model already very clearly. For the functionality of the software there's a free alternative named *no sketch engine*.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the cons of Sketch Engine? Just because it is a commercial tool doesn't make it bad, irrelevant, not so useful etc. although true one should be critical of the data and tools it provides

Comment: No, this will go much too far beyond the Q&A format of this site. But here's a reference for more food for the thought: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cost_of_Knowledge